# Knowing if my server is up or down using ping. .

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.6, ping

Thanks to all for your time.

I'm trying to know if several server are up or down using ping, and it works . . . but when **I try convert the result into a up or down, something is wrong and always is down.**

Dunno what other thing I should try, don't need anything else, just up or down and the IP.

```
import os
import datetime
import platform
import subprocess
import string

date = datetime.datetime.now()
day = date.day
hour = date.hour

def writedoc ():
    os.chdir ('Path')
    wresult = open ("pingresults_{}_{}.txt".format(day,hour), 'a')
    wresult.write ('{}-{}\n'.format(ips, rping))
    wresult.close ()

os.chdir ('Path')
openips = open ("ips.txt","r")
ipfile = openips.readlines()

for ips in ipfile:
    ips = ips.strip()
    print (ips)
    args = ["ping", "-n", "4", "-l", "1", "-w", "1000", ips]
    pping = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    rping = pping.stdout
    for line in rping:
        print (line)
    if (rping.find("(100% perdidos)" != -1)):
        result = "down"
        print (result)
    else:
        result = "up"
        print (result)
    writedoc()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rping.find("(100% perdidos)" != -1))
```

Should this instead be

```
if (rping.find("(100% perdidos)") != -1)
```

So that this checks that `rping.find("(100% perdidos)")` does not return - 1.

With your example you are effectively calling `rping.find(True)` as

`"(100% perdidos)"` does not equal - 1.